# byte array to string

Tags: java, arrays

have small problem, and would very much appreciate  help :)

I should convert byte array to string and get this output string: “[0, 0, 0, 0]”
After that another method should take the string as input and retrieve the byte array from the first one.

Im getting error that i have number.format exception, so i guess i should make convertToString method in some other way.
This is what i have so far:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;


public class byteToString {

    public String convertToString(){
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[] {91,79,44,32,79,44,32,79,44,32,79,93};  
        String holder = new String(byteArray);
        return holder;

    }
    /*was told to use this code to convert back*/
        private static byte[] toByteArray(String myString){
        myString = myString.substring(0, myString.length()- 1).substring(1);
        ByteArrayOutputStream myStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        for (StringTokenizer myTok = new StringTokenizer(myString, ","); myTok.hasMoreTokens();){
            myStream.write(Byte.parseByte(myTok.nextToken().trim()));
        }
        return myStream.toByteArray();

    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String myString = new byteToString().convertToString();

        toByteArray(myString);


    }
}
```

Thanks ahead!! :)

Comment: See `Arrays.toString(byte[])` http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(byte[])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`new byte[] {91,79,44,32,79,44,32,79,44,32,79,93}` is actually `[O, O, O, O]` array of **Oh**s not **zero**es!

Use `new byte[] {91,48,44,32,48,44,32,48,44,32,48,93}` instead.

Also want to note that you can use:

`myString = myString.substring(1, myString.length() - 1);`

instead of:

`myString = myString.substring(0, myString.length()- 1).substring(1);`.

It is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class AAA {

    public static final byte[] TEST_DATA = {91, 79, 44, 32, 79, 44, 32, 79, 44, 32, 79, 93};

    public String convertToString(byte[] array) {
        return Arrays.toString(array);
    }

    private static byte[] toByteArray(String myString) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\D*(\\d+)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(myString);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            bOut.write((byte)Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1)));
        }
        return bOut.toByteArray();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String myString = new AAA().convertToString(TEST_DATA);
        byte[] bytes = toByteArray(myString);
        System.out.println("Test " + (Arrays.equals(bytes, TEST_DATA) ? "passed" : "failed"));
    }
}
```

Comment: elegant solution, thanx! But for some reason im required to use the code from the toByteArray method i wrote....

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution for ByteArray to String is below

```
 public class ByteArrayToString {
            public static void main(String args[]) {
                byte[] random = new byte[] { 34, 65, 54 , 76, 66, 65, 66, 70, -10 };
                String utf = new String(random, "UTF-8");
                String cp1252 = new String(random, "Cp1252");
                String windows1252 = new String(random, "Windows-1252");
                System.out.println("String created from byte `enter code here`array in UTF-8 encoding : "+ utf);
                System.out.println("byte array to String in Cp1252 encoding : " + cp1252);
                System.out.println("byte array to String in Windows-1252 encoding : "+ windows1252);
            }
        }
```